# Android Marshmallow Handling Permission in Library

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am creating an Android Studio Library file (*.aar) for geo-location services which i use across multiple apps.

During the init phase of the Lib, I get the current location as below :-

```
location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

This line is giving exceptions even if I am requesting correct permissions in the main APP and declaring in APP Manifest

How do i handle the checkPermission in library(.aar) code ?

Comment: which exception is it giving? please provide your manifest as well as your code where you request the permission

Comment: Also your stack trace...

Comment: By exceptions i mean in android studio it shows lint error that "Call requires permission which may be rejected by the user". This init phase of the library part happens before the app prompts for Permissions .

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468